# Wi-Fi connection over adb fails

Tags: android, adb, android-wifi, wifi

I am trying to Connect to `wifi` with `adb` using:

```
    :/data/misc/wifi # am startservice \
>     -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \
>     -a WifiSetupService.Connect
Starting service: Intent { act=WifiSetupService.Connect cmp=com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService }
Error: Not found; no service started.
```

I get the same error running `am startservice -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService -a WifiSetupService.Reset`

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

little late, but...

The problem is that `WifiSetupService` is not installed on your device. Digged to this I have found out that this service is part of system [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/) that supports only some hw.

FYI: I had the same problem, because I tried it on android phone...

Comment: How can I install WifiSetupService?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
adb shell svc wifi disable; adb shell svc wifi enable
```

Followed by:

`am startservice \
    -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \
    -a WifiSetupService.Connect \
    -e ssid "YOURWIFINAME" \
    -e passphrase "YOURWIFIPASSWORD"`

If it fails please check logs with:

```
logcat -d | grep Wifi
```